Solving a problem with linear programming
Suppose we wish to create a speech. Assume we have $n$ words to choose from numbered from $1$ to $n$. Every word holds a list of words that can come after it $S_i$. For example: if $2 \in S_1$ then the speech can contain the sequence of words $1,2$. Every word has a length $n_i$ and a positive weight $w_i$ signifying how 'effective' this word is to the crowd.
Describe an algorithm, as efficient as possible finding a speech of exactly $l$ letters of maximal weight, given the linguistic constraints as were denoted.
For runtime complexity purposes assume $\sum S_i = s$.

An algorithm solving this in linear time is emitted using DFS.
Even so, I noticed this question is very simple to define as an LP and I wondered if it can have an efficient solution. I have provided a layout of a possible linear program. I'd like to know if this question can be solved efficiently using LP.

So I've thought of a way to compute this using a graph $G=(V,E)$ s.t:

$V = \{s,t\} \cup[n]\times[l]\cup\{0\}$
$E=\{((s,0),(i,n_i))|n_i\leq l\}\cup\\\quad\quad \{((i,m),(j,m+n_j))|j\in S_i\land m+n_j \leq l\}\cup\\\quad\quad\{((i,l),(t,0))|i\in[n]\}$
The weight function is the $w'$ is $-w$ for all edges except the ones entering $t$ which will be 0.

This is a DAG and thus i can find SSSP from $s$ to $t$ in $\approx O(n+s)$.
Now say i module the problem in the following manner:
Look for a vector $x$ s.t we maximize $\sum x_iw_{x_i}$ whilst holding:

$\sum n_{x_i}=l$
$x_i \in [n]$

Now I can transform this into standard form and run simplex algorithm.
Thanks in advance!

You might want to explore interior point algorithms, namely the Karmarkar's algorithm which has polynomial running time for solving an LP.

@codeR unfortunately we aren't covering this topic in the course I'm taking.

Then you may carefully generate instances where Simplex terminates in polynomial time.


Where did you encounter this task?  Can you credit the original source?  2. Why do you require that it be solved with linear programming?  Linear programming seems like a poor fit for this task.  This seems like an XY problem.


@D.W.I received this question as homework so I don't have any reference unfortunately. I don't require to solve this with LP (and I provided other solution). It was just so easy to define the problem as LP that I was hoping I can achieve a good runtime. I guess that I was wrong. Thanks!

Please don't use "EDIT:".  Instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.  I am not sure what your question is.  If you want to know whether there is an efficient algorithm, it sounds like you already know the answer, as you already know of an efficient algorithm.

@D.W. I hope it's clearer now than before. Thank you.
